# Excel Interop File Accessed As Read Only Despite Specifically Being Directed Not To

Tags: c#, .net, excel-interop

I am having an issue while trying to use Excel Interop with C#.NET.

Im trying to iterate through a large number of workbooks/worksheets and deposit an array of data in a range on each worksheet, as I iterate through the sheets I open, grab my range, set range number formatting, and drop my values into the range, then save and close out, and clean up all my objects.

This all works fine for a while. However, seemingly at random during the process the file will open in read only mode, which causes the SaveAs to halt and bring up a dialog (when this should be running in background for the entire time).

Some factoids:
In my Workbooks.Open() statement I am setting ReadOnly to false, IgnoreRecommendedReadOnly to true, and Notify to false, this should not only prevent the sheet from opening in read only, it should also throw an error if the file isnt able to open in read/write. This does not seem to work out for some reason, as the random read only access still happens.

I am using a sleep command in HoldWhileFileIsOpen(string) to halt the program and wait for the excel file to be completely available both before and after the excel file is used (it halts until the file is not open using `FileStream theFile = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);` as a test, this should prevent my program from opening this file until it is 100% unused/available due to the FileShare.None, but I am still getting these read only errors when saving the excel file).

I am using SaveAs to overwrite the original file with the changed version.

I am closing all COM objects and releasing them, the excel application fully exits each iteration and the task manager no longer shows excel as running each time.

I am not opening these spreadsheets or Excel itself anywhere, nor am I touching these files from anywhere besides the code snippet included below.

I want to stress that these are seemingly random, I can iterate through and save the same spreadsheet 50+ times, move on to the next spreadsheet, iterate 30 times, then hit this error. Then the next run I will only be able to iterate through the first spreadsheet 10 times before it happens again. It is not associated with a specific workbook or worksheet.

My code:

```
if (newRows.Count > 0)
{
    //Increment through our array list and build a 2D string array from that list (.Range.Value doesnt like ArrayList objects, so we must use a raw 2D array)...
    string[] rowSample = (string[])newRows[0];
    string[,] newRowsArray = new string[newRows.Count, rowSample.Length];
    int currentRowIndex = 0;
    foreach (string[] row in newRows)
    {
        int columnIndex = 0;
        foreach (string columnText in row)
        {
            newRowsArray[currentRowIndex, columnIndex] = columnText;
            columnIndex++;
        }

        currentRowIndex++;
    }

    //Hold processing while the current excel file is open, once it closes we can continue...
    HoldWhileFileIsOpen(currentExcelFile);
    try
    {
        //Open excel and open current workbook...
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        excelApplication.DisplayAlerts = false;
        excelApplication.Visible = false;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks excelWorkbooks = excelApplication.Workbooks;

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook currentWorkbook = excelWorkbooks.Open(currentExcelFile, Type.Missing, false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, false, Type.Missing, false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

        //Open up/Select our current worksheet
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets workSheets = currentWorkbook.Sheets;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet currentWorkSheet = workSheets[currentWorkSheetName];
        currentWorkSheet.Select();
        //Create new range, set range number formatting = "@" (text) to retain leading zeroes and other tricky bits in our output, then drop values into range...
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range newExcelRows = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)currentWorkSheet.get_Range(GetColumnAddress(startingColInt) + startingRow, GetColumnAddress(startingColInt + rowSample.Length - 1) + (startingRowIncrementing - 1));
        newExcelRows.NumberFormat = "@";
        //newExcelRow.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
        newExcelRows.Value = newRowsArray;

        //Save workbook changes...
        currentWorkbook.SaveAs(currentExcelFile, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

        //Close things up, all COM objects references above must be released and scrubbed thouroughly...
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(newExcelRows);
        newExcelRows = null;
        excelApplication.ActiveWorkbook.Close(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(currentWorkSheet);
        currentWorkSheet = null;
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workSheets);
        workSheets = null;
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(currentWorkbook);
        currentWorkbook = null;

        //Quit excel...
        excelWorkbooks.Close();
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelWorkbooks);
        excelWorkbooks = null;
        excelApplication.Quit();
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelApplication);
        excelApplication = null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex.Message == "Cannot save as that name. Document was opened as read-only.")
        {

        }
    }
    //Hold processing while the current excel file is open, once it closes we can continue...
    HoldWhileFileIsOpen(currentExcelFile);

    LblStatus.AppendText(" - Done modifying and saving worksheet " + currentWorkSheetName + " (" + currentCountry + ")." + Environment.NewLine);
}
else
{
    LblStatus.AppendText(" - No data found for current worksheet " + currentWorkSheetName + " (" + currentCountry + ")." + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Any assistance would be a great relief, I am not sure what is going on here or why Interop is randomly choosing to screw me during processing of these files.

Comment: I smell antivirus scanning / locking. Are there any other processes running that might be locking the file for editing?

Comment: Im really not sure, but it is a work machine so its possible. Is there a way to get around this (such as a check to see if anything is using the file or better yet a way to explicitly lock the file so nothing but my process can use it)?

Comment: The read only flag is about you being ABLE to write to it, not about file locking. It's workbook mode, not like file lock mode. Have you tried AccessMode: XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlShared in the SaveAs? Or try using Save, instead of SaveAs?

Comment: Yeah I initially was trying to Save but it had this issue as well, Ive tried all three XlSaveAsAccessMode enumerations as well, but no luck. It seems like a major oversight not to enable people to set some sort of lock on the file on .Open(), currently Im attempting to just work around the problem by catching the error in question and then re-trying the open/save after a few seconds of waiting.

Comment: Ok this work around seems to have worked: Moving all cleanup of COM objects into the Finally block, moving all instantiation/data modification before try statement, leave the SaveAs in the try block, and catch the error with message "Cannot save as that name. Document was opened as read-only.", if an error with this message is caught, set retry flag to true and sleep thread for ~3 seconds, then continue.